# Changing size of a dynamically allocated matrix

Tags: c++, matrix

Trying to re-size the shape matrix dynamically.  This is part of a drawing program where _capacity is the number of shapes drawn on a frame.

Get the error in new Shape about `_capacity` saying expression needs to have a constant value.

```
void ShapeStore::Grow(int minimumCapacity)
{   
_capacity = max (minimumCapacity, 2 * _capacity);
if (_capacity)
    {

    Shape ***newData = new Shape[_frames][_capacity];   //figure out this 
    int i;

    for (int k = 0; k < _frames; k++)
        for (i=0;i<_count;i++)
            newData[k][i] = _data[k][i];

    delete [] _data;
    _data = newData;
    }  //*/
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `std::vector`?

Comment: Why not use a `std::vector` with size `(num_rows * num_cols)` and use an addressing scheme like `data[col_index + (row_index * num_cols)]`? Because `Shape***` is just painful to look at.

Answer (score 3):

```
Shape ***newData = new Shape[_frames][_capacity];   //figure out this
```

This doesn't do what you think it does. **It only allocates an array of pointers to arrays on the free store.** Assuming that `_capacity` is a constant, each pointer in the array is a pointer to another fixed array which holds exactly `_capacity` instances of `Shape`. Here's a picture:

```
                index
            +-----------+
newData --> |     0     |  (pointer to a fixed array of _capacity instances of Shape)
            +-----------+
            |     1     |  (pointer to a fixed array of _capacity instances of Shape)
            +-----------+
            |     2     |  (pointer to a fixed array of _capacity instances of Shape)
            +-----------+
            |           |

               .......

            |           |
            +-----------+
            | _frames-1 |  (pointer to a fixed array of _capacity instances of Shape)
            +-----------+
(This is the only thing that is actually allocated)
```

The expression `new Shape[_frames][_capacity]` does not allocate enough memory to actually hold `_frame*_capacity` instances of `Shape`. Also, since each pointer in the array points to another array of *fixed* size, the compiler complains about the non-constant `_capacity` in your code snippet.

Instead of using the painfully confusing `Shape***` and `new[_frames][_capacity]` business, use a `std::vector` to hold a linear array of `Shape`s, then use an addressing scheme to emulate rows and columns, like this:

```
// Exposition only

std::vector<Shape> data;

void ResizeMatrix(std::vector<Shape>& data, int frames, int capacity)
{
    data.resize(frames * capacity);
}

// Populate data with Shapes

void IndexMatrix(int capacity_index, int frame_index, int capacity)
{
    Shape& aShape = data[capacity_index + (capacity * frame_index)];
    // Do something with it
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick feedback.  Tried using a vector earlier and since shape is an abstract class had an error saying that the abstract class could not be instantiated.  Will give them another look.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When accessing contents of `newData`, it's not `newData[k][i]` but rather `(*newData)[k][i]`

`newData` is not a two-dimensional array, it's a pointer to a two-dimensional array. Rule of thumb is each `*` at the time of declaration should be matched by one `*`, `->`, or `[]` in use.